# Marklogic Search Query not returning results for Wildcards on partial words: cts:search

Tags: xpath, full-text-search, xquery, marklogic, nosql

I am using the cts:search API in Marklogic and I've run into a wall on getting results for part of a word when I append *'s around the word for the wildcard.

I have a constraint like:

```
<constraint name="schoolName">
  <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
  <word>
    <element name="schoolName"/>
  </word>
</constraint>
```

I have a query string as:

```
let $query :='directory:/request/  schoolName:"*drivin*"'
```

The directory is a custom facet which builds a URI restriction.

The final search query is:

```
<search:query>
  <cts:and-query strength="20" qtextjoin="" qtextgroup="( )" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:directory-query depth="infinity">
      <cts:uri>/request/</cts:uri>
    </cts:directory-query>
    <cts:element-word-query qtextpre="schoolName:" qtextref="cts:annotation">
      <cts:element>schoolName</cts:element>
      <cts:annotation qtextref="following-sibling::cts:text"/>
      <cts:text>*drivin*</cts:text>
    </cts:element-word-query>
  </cts:and-query>
</search:query>
```

This returns nothing.

However changing

> *driving*

will return schoolName with driving in it. Like A AND B Driving school (case insensitive search)

Comment: You may need to enable leading/trailing element wildcards in your index settings. However, based on your example I don't think you need wildcards at all.

Comment: Got 2 questions around that:     

1. I thought adding the wildcarded in the constraint would supercede any index settings?

2. You said I don't need any asterisks, is that because of the cts:element-word-query?

And thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: ad 1. It doesn't supersede index settings, but merely makes clear how you want to match terms.
ad 2. word-queries tokenize the search string, and search for individual tokens. Could be wrong, but you might be looking for `drivin*`. The * upfront won't cross whitespace.

Comment: I would have run a test locally, but you would need to share the essential part of your code first..